# High frequency response of op-amp using Miller

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency-response

I am trying to find the -3dB freq. denoted \$f_H\$ in the following circuit, where \$R\$ has been replaced with a capacitor \$C\$. I tried doing that in two ways which yielded different results. I'd appreciate some feedback on which of the two is correct:

Applying Miller's theorem:

\$G_v=(A/sC)/(1/sC + R_{sig}(1-A))\$

First method:

\$f_H=1/(2\pi R_{sig}C(1-A)) = 1.58KHz\$

Second method:

I tried to determine the frequency at which the voltage gain decreases by a factor of \$\sqrt2\$, hence:

\$(A/sC)/(1/sC + R_{sig}(1-A)) = A/\sqrt 2\$

Substituting \$s=j\omega\$, yielded \$f_H=4.1KHz\$[image]

Comment: Your text talks about an opamp yet your schematic shows an amplifier (not an opamp). Is is unclear what the sign of A is which is **quite essential** as it changes the functionality of the circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry about that.. A is negative.

Comment: @peripatein 3dB frequency is equal to \$f_H= \frac{1}{2\pi R_{sig}C(1+|A|)}\$

Comment: @G36 Great, thanks! How may I now find the frequency of the unity gain? Must I first determine the BW?

Comment: For the ideal integrator with op-amp the unity gain frequency is equal to \$F = \frac{1}{2 \pi R_{sig}C}\$. And your gain \$A\$ is frequency dependent or not ?

Comment: @G36 A is constant, frequency independent. Doesn't the unity grain frequency need to be calculated using the BW or perhaps using \$f_H\$?

Comment: Try to use a Miller's theorem and notice that you have a voltage divider (Rsin + C*(1+|A|)) and amplifier with the gain equal to A.

Comment: And the right answer is \$ F_T = \frac{\sqrt{A^2 -1}}{2\pi R_{sig}C(1+A)} \$  and if you take the limit when A approaches to infinity you will get \$ F_T = \frac{1}{2\pi R_{sig}C} \$

Comment: @G36 How did you derive that expression? What I get for the voltage divider and after using Miller's theorem is basically \$V_{in}=(V_{sig}/[sc(1-A)])/[1/[sc(1-A)] + R_{sig}]\$. How do I proceed? Don't I need to demand \$V_{out}/V_{in}=1\$?

Comment: Anyone willing to remark on my attempt concerning the unity-gain frequency?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to find the unity-gain frequency you can use this trick that will work for this practical circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj8KAz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hence \$V_X = \frac{\frac{1}{s C1 (1+A)}}{R1+\frac{1}{s C1 (1+A)}}\$

And because we are interested only in magnitude we can write:

$$V_X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{F}{F_H})^2}}$$

Where the \$F\$ - is a signal frequency and \$F_H\$ - is -3dB frequency.

And finally we have:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{F}{F_H})^2}} * |A| = 1  $$

All you need is to solve for \$F\$

Hence the unity-gain frequency is

$$F_T = \frac{1}{2 \pi R_1 C_1} * \frac{\sqrt{A^2 -1}}{|A|+1}$$

Of-course the unity-gain frequency can also be find from transfer function directly.

Comment: how may I arrive at the same result using the transfer function?

Comment: First you need do find the transfer function